# Is it safe to reassign a NSArray pointer during a for : in loop?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multithreading

Thread 1:

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
/* load array */
```

Thread 2:

```
for (NSObject* object in self.array) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Is this safe?  When and how often does self.array get accessed during the for : in loop?

If I reassign self.array, during the loop, will Thread 2 continue to peacefully loop through the old instance or will it switch to the new instance, potentially causing a mutation exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `for/in` loop, the collection is an expression. In your case, that expression is `self.array`. The program calculates the value of that expression once, at the start of the loop. In your case, it calls `self.array` once at the start of the loop.

You can safely replace `self.array` with another array while the loop is executing.

What you **cannot** do is modify the array in-place while the loop is executing. That is, you cannot replace one element with another element, or add an element, or remove an element. If you do, you will get a run-time error (because the `NSFastEnumeration` implementation in `NSArray` explicitly checks for mutations).

Comment: I had just run some tests that bear this out.  But, in thinking about it further I think the real problem is that the old instance will now be released and the loop will be accessing a released object.

Comment: ARC will retain the object returned by `self.array` at the start of the loop, and release it at the end of the loop.

Comment: Wow, that's nice.  So I don't need to cast it to a local strong pointer then?

Comment: You don't need to cast `self.array`.